# DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is not a valid value for property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, unity-container

I have the following code in my `Bootstrapper` class:

```
protected override void InitializeShell() {
    Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell; //520
    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    try
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show(); //720
    }
    catch (ArgumentException exp)
    {
        // avoid RadRibbonWindow.AttachToWindowInteropHandle exceptions when closing window
    }
}
```

When my code hits the line `Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();` my debugger catches the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}'
> is not a valid value for property 'BorderBrush'.'

I suspect the `UnsetValue` may come from `WindowStyle.None`, but because an `AllowTransparency` somewhere is `True`, that is the only window style I am allowed to use.

Other occasions of this problem that my Googling has found provide more specifics, but none fit my scenario, and I don't know what other details I should find and share. What areas of my application should I look at for debugging this?

Comment: Which code/xaml/style sets the `BorderBrush` to `UnsetValue`? `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`? Are all resource dictionaries included?

Comment: It looks like `DynamicResource` as the main window as `Style="{DynamicResource SARDSWindowStyle}"`. I can't find the text `SARDSWindowStyle` anywhere else in the app, and suspect the resource is supposed to be loaded from a dll

Comment: I meant: the `BorderBrush` that supposedly is set to `UnsetValue`, how and where is it set? In code, in xaml, in a style, to a static resource or a dynamic one?

Comment: I found this setter: `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlOuterBorder_Normal}"/>` and a message that says `ControlOuterBorder_Normal` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

> I found this setter: `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlOuterBorder_Normal}"/>` and a message that says `ControlOuterBorder_Normal` is not found.

Either use `DynamicResource` or include (merge) the `ResourceDictionary` that contains `ControlOuterBorder_Normal` (or define it if it isn't defined anywhere).